# Levels of a dataframe after filtering

Tags: r, filtering

i've been doing an assignment for a self study in R programming. I have a question about what happens with factors in a dataframe once you filter it. I have a dataframe that has the columns (movie)Studio and Genre.
For the assignment i need to filter it. I succeeded in this, but when i check the levels of the newly filtered columns all factors are still present, so not only the filtered ones.

Why is this? Am i doing something wrong?

```
StudioTarget <- c("Buena Vista Studios","Fox","Paramount Pictures","Sony","Universal","WB")
GenreTarget <- c("action","adventure","animation","comedy","drama")

dftest <- df[df$Studio %in% StudioTarget & df$Genre %in% GenreTarget,]

> levels(dftest$Studio)
 
[1] "Art House Studios"        "Buena Vista Studios"      "Colombia Pictures"       
[4] "Dimension Films"          "Disney"                   "DreamWorks"              
[7] "Fox"                      "Fox Searchlight Pictures" "Gramercy Pictures"       
[10] "IFC"                      "Lionsgate"                "Lionsgate Films"         
[13] "Lionsgate/Summit"         "MGM"                      "MiraMax"                 
[16] "New Line Cinema"          "New Market Films"         "Orion"                   
[19] "Pacific Data/DreamWorks"  "Paramount Pictures"       "Path_ Distribution"      
[22] "Relativity Media"         "Revolution Studios"       "Screen Gems"             
[25] "Sony"                     "Sony Picture Classics"    "StudioCanal"             
[28] "Summit Entertainment"     "TriStar"                  "UA Entertainment"        
[31] "Universal"                "USA"                      "Vestron Pictures"        
[34] "WB"                       "WB/New Line"              "Weinstein Company"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `droplevels(dftest$Studio)` to remove unused levels

Answer (score 0):

No, you're not doing anything wrong.  A factor defines a fixed number of levels.  These levels remain the same even if one or more of them are not present in the data.  You've asked for the levels of your factor, not the values present after filtering.

Consider:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(cyl= as.factor(cyl)) %>% 
  filter(cyl == 4) %>% 
  distinct(cyl) %>% 
  pull(cyl)
[1] 4
Levels: 4 6 8
```

Welcome to SO.  Next time, pleasetry to provide a *minumum working example*.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help you construct one.